# Finding last column of a found row with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I'm trying to find last column of a foundcell row and faced an error in my codes.
Prethanks for your favor and here isw my codes:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim searchValue As String
    Dim foundCell As Range
    Dim LR As Long
    Dim LC As Long
    Dim embeddedChart As ChartObject

    searchValue = TextBox1.Text
    

    If searchValue = "" Then Exit Sub

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        LR = Worksheets("Report").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Set foundCell = ws.Cells.Find(What:=searchValue, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
        LC = ws.Cells(foundCell.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
            Worksheets("Report").Range("A" & LR + 1).Value = ws.Name
            Worksheets("Report").Range("B" & LR + 1).Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
            Worksheets("Report").Range("C" & LR + 1).Value = foundCell.Offset(0, LC).Value
        End If
    Next ws
   Call SpecifyAChartType
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line throws the error? What's the error number and text?

Comment: line LC
Error 91 :Object variable or with block variable not set

Answer (score 1):

- If `foundCell` is nothing (can't find `searchValue`), then `foundCell.Row` throws runtime error.
- Please move `LC =  ...` after `If` clause.
- Always qualify the range reference with the sheet object. eg. `ws.Columns.Count`.

```vb
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        LR = Worksheets("Report").Cells(Worksheets("Report").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Set foundCell = ws.Cells.Find(What:=searchValue, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
        If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
            LC = ws.Cells(foundCell.Row, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            Worksheets("Report").Range("A" & LR + 1).Value = ws.Name
            Worksheets("Report").Range("B" & LR + 1).Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
            Worksheets("Report").Range("C" & LR + 1).Value = foundCell.Offset(0, LC).Value
        End If
    Next ws
```

Comment: Thanks its works but it turns back to me the value of first column of foundcell row, not last!

Comment: Which cell are you talk about? Add `Debug.Print LC` after `LC = ... `, then you can chech its value in VBE Immediate window. Or debug the code to check it in VBE Local windows.

Comment: Be carefull, `foundCell.Offset(0, LC)` is wrong: If `foundCell` is in column A(=1) and LC = 10, `Offset(0, 10)` will access column K (=11)

Comment: Thanks so much buddy. i handled it with countA function.

Answer (score 1):

### Find the Last Non-Blank Cell in a Row Using the `Find` Method

- The main issue with your code is covered in **taller**'s answer.
- If you have formulas that evaluate to an empty string in cells of a range, you can use the *Find* method with its *LookIn* argument set to `xlValues` to ignore those cells. Both, the *End* property and the *Find* method with its *LookIn* argument set to `xlFormulas` will find those cells because they are not empty, they are just blank.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    
    Dim SearchString As String: SearchString = TextBox1.Text
    If SearchString = "" Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets("Report")
    Dim dcell As Range: Set dcell = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet, srg As Range, scell As Range
    
    For Each sws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ' To exclude the destination sheet, wrap all of it in:
        'If Not sws Is dws Then
        'End If
        Set srg = sws.UsedRange ' usually you know the column and first row!?
        ' top-left-most partial case-insensitive match e.g.
        ' if 'C1, F1, A2' then 'C1' (for 'A2' use 'xlByColumns')
        Set scell = srg.Find(SearchString, srg.Cells(srg.Cells.CountLarge), _
            xlValues, xlPart, xlByRows)
        If Not scell Is Nothing Then
            dcell.Value = sws.Name
            dcell.Offset(, 1).Value = scell.Offset(, 1).Value
            ' right-most non-blank cell ('xlValues') in row (maybe 'scell'!)
            Set scell = scell.Resize(srg.Column + srg.Columns.Count _
                - scell.Column).Find("*", scell, xlValues, , , xlPrevious)
            dcell.Offset(, 2).Value = scell.Value
            Set dcell = dcell.Offset(1) ' next destination cell (row)
        End If
    Next sws
    
    ' Irrelevant!?
    'Dim embeddedChart As ChartObject
    'Call SpecifyAChartType

End Sub
```